# How to login different type of users using Spring-Boot 2.0 and OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have different types of users that I want to authenticate with a single authorization server. Each one has a database table and will log in through a different client. I want to be able to know from which db table I have to look to authenticate them. So I try to get the clientID from the request, but I can't. Here is what I've tried:

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Authentication authentication =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String clientID = ((OAuth2Authentication) authentication).getOAuth2Request().getClientId();


        if (clientID.equals("clientID1")){
            //look at the user table
        }
        else if (clientID.equals("clientID2")){
            //look at the company table
        }
        else
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("ClientID " + clientID + " not found.");
    }
```

The piece of code above compiles fine but the problem happens at runtime with a cast exception like this:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication"
}
```

So My questions are: How can I get the clientID from the request ? Or is there another strategy I can use to authenticate my different users?         Any help is appreciated.